# Shift 10-15v to 0-5v

Tags: level-shifting

I'm looking to shift 10-15v to 0-5v to read with the Analog input of an arduino.

I've seen some solutions with an OpAmp but all require a negative rail which I do not have.

I know I could use a simple resistive divider but then I lose out on resolution.  Any suggestions or a direction you could point me would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You could shift the 10-15V to something like 0.5 to 4.5V with a single 5V supply and you would not lose out much on resolution. You can use pretty much any op-amp that meets your precision requirements and has a rail-to-rail output.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVpR8A.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

One advantage of using a single 5V supply and giving up that 20% resolution is that you don't need to worry about clamping the op-amp output at the MCU rails.

Comment: Thanks! this looks like exactly what I'm looking for.  Is there a name for this circuit so I can familiarize myself with it and not just copy :)

Comment: It’s a kind of difference amplifier with a 5:1 attenuator on the input plus a 2.5V reference (to do the shifting) formed by D1 & R5. The output is 0.8Vin - 7.5V. A more general circuit would have a resistor from the inverting input to ground, but I optimized that away for you.

Comment: Note that the attenuation followed by amplification mean op-amp Vos and TCVos are more important than if we had a high voltage rail, but it’s easy to get inexpensive amplifiers with extremely good specs in that department, especially for only 10 bits ADC.

Answer (score 0):

If accuracy matters, the only real good way without some sort of negative rail to make a divider with, is to use an op-amp.

You can get rail to rail op amps that only require positive voltage and can get within ~50mV of the ground rail. If that is good enough, just look for "rail to rail" amps. There are many.